# Equinumerosity: Proof Validation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

**Synopsis**

In my studying of Set Theory, I've had the privilege of being able to compare much of my work to a solutions manual. This solutions manual, however, ended after the chapter on the various number systems. As such, I'm going to start posting a lot of my own personal solutions or questions onto the site for either proof validation or proof hints (if I'm unable to find the solution in other places), and I would greatly appreciate any feedback on my mathematical writing. Thank you.

**Exercise**

Show that the equation $$f(m, n) = 2^m(2n + 1) - 1$$ defines a one-to-one correspondence between $\omega \times \omega$ and $\omega$.

**Proof**

First, we show that $f$ is injective. Consider $(m, n)$ and $(m', n')$ in $\omega \times \omega$. Now suppose that $f(m, n) = f(m', n')$. Then $2^{m}(2n+1) - 1 = 2^{m'}(2n' + 1) - 1$ and $2^{m}(2n+1) = 2^{m'}(2n' + 1)$. Note that every value of this equation will only have one odd factor, mainly $(2n + 1)$. As such, $n = n'$ and $2^m = 2^{m'}$. So, $m = m'$ and $f$ is injective.

Next, we wish to show that $f$ is surjective. Consider any $x \in \omega$. If $x$ is even, take $m = 0$ and $n = x/2$. If $x$ is odd, note that $x = 2k + 1$ for some $k \in \omega$. So $2k = 2^m(2n + 1)$ if $m$ and $n$ exist, and since every even number contains a factor that is odd (for powers of two, we consider the factor one), there is always a $m$ and $n$ that satisfies the equality. Therefore, for any $x \in \omega$, there is always a $m$ and $n$ such that $f(m, n) = 2^m(2n + 1) - 1$ and $f$ is surjective.

As such, because $f$ is both surjective and injective, $f$ is bijective, and the equation $f(m, n) = 2^m(2n + 1) - 1$ defines a one-to-one correspondence between $\omega \times \omega$ and $\omega$.

Comment: I think you meant to take $n=x/2$ when $x$ is even, but other than that, I believe this is correct. The shortest way to prove this is by appealing to the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. It's that theorem which tells you why if $2^m(2n+1)=2^{m'}(2n'+1)$, then $m=m'$ and $2n+1=2n'+1$. And the theorem would shorten your proof of surjectivity considerably.

Comment: I see. I've never heard of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. I'll look into it. Thank you!

Comment: The theorem essentially just says that every positive integer has a unique prime factorization (unique up to reordering of the prime powers).

Comment: I see! I didn't know that was a theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proof looks fine.

For the $x$ odd case, you might want to clarify whether when using $n=0$ for the "odd factor one" interferes with $k$ itself being odd (hence $m=1$).

It might be easier to simply write down $m$ and $n$ in terms of the factorization of $k$ (at least for prime $2$ and everything else).

This tracks closer to why this entire construction works: you're essentially splitting up all natural numbers into the direct product of two copies of itself, one half encoded by powers of 2, the other half by all odd numbers. Fundamental theorem of arithmetic makes this work both ways (per **Anonymous**).

Comment: Actually, would you be willing to clarify how I might use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic to shorten my proof? Would it just be something like "since every even number has at least one odd prime factor, there is always an $m$ and $n$ that satisfy the equality?"

Comment: It's closer to: every number has a unique factorization. In particular, it will factor into the form $2^m$ times an odd number (which is just the product of all the possibly repeated odd prime factors). Now note that 1. "every number has a unique factorization" includes odd numbers, and 2. any $2^m$ times any odd number is a valid integer.

Comment: I see. That makes a lot more sense. Thank you so much!